# Why Server Class Machine Default Collector in java can't be used on 32bit windows?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Recently I was asked what kind of garbage collector will be used in 32bit windows JVM ?

I answered The "Serial Garbage Collector". Then the question was why not Server class machine collector (condition provided machine has more than 2GB of RAM and and More than 2 virtual processor to fulfill the server class machine requirement ) and why this exception is there ?

Can someone explain me this

Answer (score 0):

From the book, Java Performance : The Definitive Guide by Scott Oaks, this is how client and server machines are defined as according to Oracle HotSpot VM - it usually depends on a combination of OS & number of CPUs on the machine but for Windows 32-bit, they made an exception :)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        OS                                       Default compiler
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Windows, 32-bit, any number of CPUs            -client
    Windows, 64-bit, any number of CPUs            -server
    MacOS, any number of CPUs                      -server
    Linux/Solaris, 32-bit, 1 CPU                   -client
    Linux/Solaris, 32-bit, 2 or more CPUs          -server
    Linux, 64-bit, any number of CPUs              -server
    Solaris, 32-bit/64-bit overlay, 1 CPU          -client
    Solaris, 32-bit/64-bit overlay, 2 or more CPUs -server (32-bit mode)
```

Comment: So this has been defined in that way without any reason ?

Comment: Not sure about the reason but I think may be it's a limitation of old Windows 32-bit OS like XP sp1 or below to make use of multiple CPUs. XP sp2 and above (vista, w7) have support for multiple CPUs even in 32-bit version.

Comment: I'm not sure what you found in that book applies to modern day Java. The difference between `server` and `client` setting becomes less and less relevant as most platforms graduate towards 64-bit and a decent supply of RAM. For 64-bit platforms there's no longer something called `client` option (option will be ignored). See [Server-Class Machine Detection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html) for more information.